FamilyActivitySelection tokens are invalid for other members of Family Sharing Network
I'm currently working with the FamilyControls API and testing my app on two different devices. Both devices are in the same family-sharing network with one phone being the owner of the network (I'll call this A) and the other one being an adult in the same network(I'll call this B).
When device A picks apps using the FamilyActivityPicker, it shares that selection with device B (via encoding, sending over network, and decoding on device B). However, interacting with the tokens from that selection on device B (displaying it, using it in shield) throws an error saying the token is null.
From the documentation, I thought every token would be the same across all devices in the family sharing network. So my question:

How do I send the FamilyActivitySelection from A to B and have the tokens still be functional?

Does this functionality only work if A is a "parent" and B is a "child" in the family sharing network?


From the documentation, I thought that a token from one device in a family sharing network would work for everyone in the network.
Also, side note: If I reverse the process and send the tokens from B to A. Interacting with the token on device A works exactly as expected. For some reason, it's only going from A to B where it doesn't work.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
